# AWS ecr get-login-password credential issue in Python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I'm writing a python script to push a docker image to Elastic Container Registry. In the script below, I set my AWS CLI credentials using environment variables programmatically, as my credentials are generated for each invocation.

```
env = os.environ.copy()
env['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "my-region"
env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = "ACCESS_KEY_ID_I_KNOW_WORKS"
env['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = "SECRET_KEY_I_KNOW_WORKS"

#Working credentials can be seen in this command output, proving(?) that they are usable
subprocess.call(f'aws configure list', shell=True, env=env)

#This fails despite 'aws configure list' showing the working credentials
subprocess.call(f'aws ecr get-login-password --region my-region', shell=True, env=env)
```

This script gives me this error for the last command:

```
An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

Now, running each command (exporting the environment variables) directly in bash works just fine, but the script does not. I've also tried several variations of using profiles stored in ~/.aws but none of them give me better results.

I'm not sure why AWS CLI seemingly does not pick up the credentials. Any idea what I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you give permissions to your user for the ECR service?

Comment: Does it work without boto3?

Comment: @DerekMenénedez yes, the user has permissions for the ECR service. I was able to use the same credentials generated by my script manually, but I want aws cli to pick them up automatically.

Comment: @Marcin That's a good question. I was hoping to avoid boto3 because 1) this is a very simple script and 2) boto3 still requires aws configure as far as I can tell, so it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

I mentioned that my credentials were generated on each invocation.

It turns out I can't use those credentials immediately, I have to wait roughly 10 seconds between generation and usage.

So, I simply added a sleep between creation and usage:

```
creds = generateCredentials()

time.sleep(10)

env = os.environ.copy()
env['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = "my-region"
env['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = creds.aws_access_key_id
env['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = creds.secret_access_key

...
```

This explains why the credentials seem to work when I put them in by hand, when in fact I'm just slower than a script.

Another option is to request credentials at the beginning of the script, then do other stuff like run a build, then come back and use them, if that works for you.